# Using multiple advanced parameters with Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use both advanced parameters with Google's [copyTo function.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))
The first two work:

```
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true});

sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:false});
```

However this does not.

```
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true}, {formatOnly:false});
```

Am I making a formatting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And immediately after posting I worked it out, it's supposed to be like this:

```
sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly:true, formatOnly:false});
```